# Can't install Java 8 in Xubuntu 18.04

Tags: software-installation, java, oracle

I can't install Java 8 in Xubuntu 18.04/

```
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
[sudo] password for user: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
oracle-java8-installer is already the newest version (8u201-1~webupd8~1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 197 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up oracle-java8-installer (8u201-1~webupd8~1) ...
Using wget settings from /var/cache/oracle-jdk8-installer/wgetrc
Downloading Oracle Java 8...
--2019-04-17 21:34:46--  http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u201-b09/42970487e3af4f5aa5bca3f542482c60/jdk-8u201-linux-x64.tar.gz
Resolving download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)... 23.32.64.102
Connecting to download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)|23.32.64.102|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Moved Temporarily
Location: https://edelivery.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u201-b09/42970487e3af4f5aa5bca3f542482c60/jdk-8u201-linux-x64.tar.gz [following]
--2019-04-17 21:34:46--  https://edelivery.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u201-b09/42970487e3af4f5aa5bca3f542482c60/jdk-8u201-linux-x64.tar.gz
Resolving edelivery.oracle.com (edelivery.oracle.com)... 88.221.34.197, 2600:1403:2:59e::366, 2600:1403:2:580::366
Connecting to edelivery.oracle.com (edelivery.oracle.com)|88.221.34.197|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Moved Temporarily
Location: http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u201-b09/42970487e3af4f5aa5bca3f542482c60/jdk-8u201-linux-x64.tar.gz?AuthParam=1555551407_c7bf9550ae418012627e2e12b0261dc8 [following]
--2019-04-17 21:34:47--  http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u201-b09/42970487e3af4f5aa5bca3f542482c60/jdk-8u201-linux-x64.tar.gz?AuthParam=1555551407_c7bf9550ae418012627e2e12b0261dc8
Connecting to download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)|23.32.64.102|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 301 Moved Permanently
Location: https://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u201-b09/42970487e3af4f5aa5bca3f542482c60/jdk-8u201-linux-x64.tar.gz?AuthParam=1555551407_c7bf9550ae418012627e2e12b0261dc8 [following]
--2019-04-17 21:34:47--  https://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u201-b09/42970487e3af4f5aa5bca3f542482c60/jdk-8u201-linux-x64.tar.gz?AuthParam=1555551407_c7bf9550ae418012627e2e12b0261dc8
Connecting to download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)|23.32.64.102|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2019-04-17 21:34:50 ERROR 404: Not Found.

download failed
Oracle JDK 8 is NOT installed.
dpkg: error processing package oracle-java8-installer (--configure):
 installed oracle-java8-installer package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 oracle-java8-installer
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Please run this instead `LANG=C sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer`.

Comment: screenshot :
http://i.imgur.com/pf5rwnm.png

Answer (score 4):

Same problem in the Ubuntu 14.

This is due to the fact that Oracle has moved from 201 to 211 version, removing 201 from its resource. And webupd8team did not have correct the links.

Check this solution:

```
mkdir -p /opt/jdk
wget https://download.oracle.com/otn/java/jdk/8u211-b12/478a62b7d4e34b78b671c754eaaf38ab/jdk-8u211-linux-x64.tar.gz?AuthParam=1555549457_a97b02ea0e2d39aeaf0e2a1d180a6b7e
```

Manual download from [here](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html), we need `jdk-8u211-linux-x64.tar.gz` or `jdk-8uXXX-linux-x64.tar.gz`

```
tar -zxf jdk-8u211-linux-x64.tar.gz -C /opt/jdk/

update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /opt/jdk/jdk1.8.0_211/bin/java 100
update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/javac javac /opt/jdk/jdk1.8.0_211/bin/javac 100

update-alternatives --display java
update-alternatives --display javac

java -version
```

For cancel installation in every time when apt-get update will be running:

```
apt-get remove oracle-java8-installer
apt-get purge oracle-java8-installer
apt-mark hold oracle-java8-installer
```

Comment: I am getting an error ~ sudo wget https://download.oracle.com/otn/java/jdk/8u211-b12/478a62b7d4e34b78b671c754eaaf38ab/jdk-8u211-linux-x64.tar.gz?AuthParam=1555549457_a97b02ea0e2d39aeaf0e2a1d180a6b7e

zsh: no matches found: https://download.oracle.com/otn/java/jdk/8u211-b12/478a62b7d4e34b78b671c754eaaf38ab/jdk-8u211-linux-x64.tar.gz?AuthParam=1555549457_a97b02ea0e2d39aeaf0e2a1d180a6b7e

Comment: Hi Olesya, and welcome to Stack Exchange! The `wget` URL won’t work for me either. Could the `AuthParam=1555549457_a97b02ea0e2d39aeaf0e2a1d180a6b7e` be related to your personal authenticated session, and have become invalid by now?

Comment: Oracle now requires an account to download new versions of Java, after its license changed (btw now it's offered at no cost only for personal and development use, requiring a commercial license for everything else), that's why it doesn't work, and why the PPA will probably not be updated.

Comment: On a side note don't use wget command. This is a one time link provided to a particular IP for particular timestamp. Instead download JDK from [Oracle's site](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html). You need to authenticate for that.