# Can't install Oracle Java 8 in Ubuntu 18.10

Tags: server, java

I've tried to install java with

```
# add-apt-repository -y ppa:webupd8team/java
# apt update
# apt install oracle-java8-installer
```

but got error:

```
ERROR 404: Not Found.

download failed
**Oracle JDK 8 is NOT installed.
```

I've search internet and found solution:

```
cd /var/lib/dpkg/info
sudo sed -i 's|JAVA_VERSION=8u201|JAVA_VERSION=8u211|' oracle-java8-installer.*
sudo sed -i 's|PARTNER_URL=http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u201-b09/42970487e3af4f5aa5bca3f542482c60/|PARTNER_URL=https://download.oracle.com/otn/java/jdk/8u211-b12/478a62b7d4e34b78b671c754eaaf38ab/|' oracle-java8-installer.*
sudo sed -i 's|SHA256SUM_TGZ="cb700cc0ac3ddc728a567c350881ce7e25118eaf7ca97ca9705d4580c506e370"|SHA256SUM_TGZ="c0b7e45330c3f79750c89de6ee0d949ed4af946849592154874d22abc9c4668d"|' oracle-java8-installer.*
sudo sed -i 's|J_DIR=jdk1.8.0_201|J_DIR=jdk1.8.0_211|' oracle-java8-installer.*
```

But now i have another error:

```
Resolving login.oracle.com (login.oracle.com)... 156.151.58.18
Connecting to login.oracle.com (login.oracle.com)|156.151.58.18|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 401 Authorization Required

Username/Password Authentication Failed.
download failed
Oracle JDK 8 is NOT installed.
dpkg: error processing package oracle-java8-installer (--configure):
 installed oracle-java8-installer package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 oracle-java8-installer
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

What is this 401 authorization? I should enter credentials anywhere? Please help!

Comment: You may download `jdk-8u212-linux-x64.tar.gz` (185.98 MB) directly from https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html and install it at `/opt/jvm` or any where you wish.

Comment: When you download from oracle website, [you need credentials](https://profile.oracle.com/myprofile/account/create-account.jspx). If you don't pass correct string during download, you will get `401 authorization error`.  From `/var/lib/dpkg/info`, the URL that contains string `42970487e3af4f5aa5bca3f542482c60` which may be incorrect.

Comment: This PPA has been discontinued. Better not to use this PPA anymore. [Reference](https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/ubuntu/java).

Comment: Kulfy,

That mean we should use another repositories for autoinstallation or install Java JDK manually?


BTW I've installed 8u211 manually, but that was a bit complicated. And sudo dpkg --list | grep -i jdk doesnt show it. Not sure this is ok.

Comment: Oracle made it hard to use PPA, so I'll suggest install manually. Moreover since Oracle JDK isn't a Debian package but simply a folder containing necessary files which is used by updating alternatives, therefore it would not be there in dpkg list. Also dpkg command won't help you in updating/removing JDK. You have to replace/delete folder or update alternatives.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't install Java 8 in Xubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1134789/)

Answer (score 1):

Azul manages and provides for free very functional packages of OpenJDK, from 7 to 12.
As per their [instructions](https://docs.azul.com/zulu/zuludocs/#ZuluUserGuide/PrepareZuluPlatform/AttachAPTRepositoryUbuntuOrDebianSys.htm%3FTocPath%3DZulu%2520Installation%2520Guide%7CPrepare%2520the%2520Zulu%2520Installation%2520Platform%7CAttach%2520Azul%2520Package%2520Repositories%7C_____2), to install one or more java version you just need to do:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 0xB1998361219BD9C9
sudo apt-add-repository 'deb http://repos.azulsystems.com/ubuntu stable main'
sudo apt-install zulu-8
```

to have a fully functional java 8 environment. If you want to have more than one java versions installed you can choose the default one as usually done in debian/ubuntu:

```
update-java-alternatives -l                # to list available ones
update-java-alternatives -s zulu-8-amd64   # to set java8 as default
```